# How to replace strings between characters '/' in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string say "abcd/data/efgh". Now I need to replace text between two '/' character in this string with some other data.

for ex: I want "abcd/data/efgh" to be replaced with "abcd/newtext/efgh".

how can I do it with reg exp in javascript?

Comment: Have you already tried something and failed?

Comment: can you show what you have so far? have you looked at [http://www.regexr.com/](http://www.regexr.com/)

Answer (score 1):

Using replace, but because javascript doesn't have lookbehinds, you need to replace it with a string concatenated with slashes:

```
var x = 'abcd/data/efgh';
var s = 'newtext';
console.log(x.replace(/\/[^/]+\//, '/'+s+'/'));// gives: abcd/newtext/efgh
```

Answer (score 0):

Have e try with:

```
'abcd/data/efgh'.replace(/\/[^/]+\//, '/newtest/')
```

**Output:**

```
abcd/newtest/efgh
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
"abcd/data/efgh".replace(/\/(.+)\//, '/newtext/')
```

or

```
"abcd/data/efgh".replace(/^(.+\/)(.+)(\/.+)$/, '$1newtext$3')
```

Answer (score 0):

you should try this code snippet

```
var x = 'abcd/data/efgh';
var s = 'newtext';
console.log(x.replace(/(/.[^/]+/)/g, '/'+s+'/'));
```

Hope this would help you.
Thanks!!